# IOS - How to rotate image at some degree

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgaffinetransform

I want to rotate image with some angle as show in the below image.

[image]

I am trying to with that

```
CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(degrees));
imageView.transform = t;
```

I am not getting output like this. even I am not close with this.

Comment: what output are you getting ?

Comment: You need to give us more to go on, as what you've written should work. A screen shot of what you're getting, some more code etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is the code I used to rotate an image by 30 degrees**

```
 UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 400)];
 imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"maxresdefault.jpg"];
 [self.view addSubview:imgView];
 float degrees = 30.0f;
 float radians = (degrees* M_PI/180);
 imgView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(radians, 0, 0, 1.0);
```

**The Simulator ScreenShot before transform**

[image]

**Here is the Simulator ScreenShot after Transform**

[image]

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Yes its what i am expecting. thannks

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. You can also rotate in the anticlockwise direction by using negative degree value

Answer (score 0):

Reset by transform before apply other transforms...

```
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity  
// i hope your angle is proper calculate
CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(degrees));
imageView.transform = t;
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: That won't help - directly applying a transform using the '..Make..' functions replaces any previous transform that has been set. In fact it will cause the image to be transformed twice.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the layer.transform like below in swift

```
imageView?.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(M_PI_2)))
```

**For Objective C :**

```
imageView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeAffineTransform(CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2));
```